# Convert MySQL Timestamp to Local Time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, datejs

I've seen a few questions about this, however none seem to be a universal solution for all browsers.

On my webpage I'm fetching a MYSQL Timestamp 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' in UTC. However, I need to convert this timestamp in Javascript to display just time in local meridian format... (i.e.. 8:00 pm).

The closest solution i found was appending 'UTC' to the MySQL timstamp string and creating a date object like that. However, this solution doesn't work in Safari. In anyone's knows of a solution please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is also `moment timezone` that may provide a cross-browser way to do what you want. See: http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score 2):

First convert MySql date string into JavaScript Date object. Then convert this gmt date object to local date object.

```
function mysqlGmtStrToJSDate(str) {

        var t = str.split(/[- :]/);

        // Apply each element to the Date function
        return new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);

    }

    function mysqlGmtStrToJSLocal(str) {
        // first create str to Date object
        var g = mysqlGmtStrToJSDate(str);
        // 
        return new Date(g.getTime() - ( g.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000 ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting the MySQL `timestamp` to `Date` object in JS and then using `getTimezoneOffset()` is a valid way to do it. According to the ECMAScript specification the `Date` should look something like this : `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`, so you should format the date correctly ( `string replace(' ', 'T')` )

If it is still not working, this is a list of date formats working across all browsers as described [here](http://biostall.com/javascript-new-date-returning-nan-in-ie-or-invalid-date-in-safari)

> ```
> var d = new Date(2011, 01, 07); 
> var d = new Date(2011, 01, 07, 11, 05, 00);  
> var d = new Date("02/07/2011"); 
> var d = new Date("02/07/2011 11:05:00");
> var d = new Date(1297076700000);
> var d = new Date("Mon Feb 07 2011 11:05:00 GMT");
> ```

Comment: where would getTimeZoneOffSet() be used?

Comment: you will have `var date = new Date(); date.setTime(1297076700000 - (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000)); dateString = date.toUTCString();`